# std::cin into char array skips spaces?

Tags: c++, stdin

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>

#define BUFF 100

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char input[BUFF];

    cout << "Input:\n>";

    cin >> input;

    cout << "\n\nOutput:" << input;

    cin >> input;
    cin >> input;
}
```

How come when you read input into a char array it skips the spaces? oh and there is 2 cin's(at the end) because it acts a little strange and exits if a space is entered when there is 1 cin...not sure why either.

EG

i enter `cup cake` and it outputs `cup`

Comment: What do you mean it skips the spaces? Give example please.

Comment: @George i type cup cake and it outputs cup

Comment: The code is wrong. If I give input greater than the BUFFER size it will keep storing it, eventually corrupting memory. Check `getline` which reads in a string (the class).

Comment: @George Kastrinis thats not my issue

Comment: @Flyphe: That doesn't mean you shouldn't fix it. That's why he said it in a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @Nicol +1 true yes(and thank you) i will but i want it to work firstly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically because `operator>>` for `std::cin` takes one "input object" between whitespaces (i.e. , `\t`, `\n`) and reads it into given variable/object. Try:

```
std::string input[2];
std::cout << "Input:\n>";
std::cin >> input[0] >> input[1];
```

For input `cup cake` you will get `input[0] == "cup"` and `input[1] == "cake"`.

If you don't read whole input it stays in the input buffer; that is why you need two `cin >> input` at the end of `main()`, which made you confused. The explanation is that you read `"cup"` into `input`, but `"cake"` stays in buffer ready for next read.

This behaviour is very handy when reading into several variables, e.g.:

```
int a, b, c;
std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
```

This allows you to write three integers separated by whitespace and they'll get read into proper variables. If you need whole line of input, try as suggested by David Rodríguez and use `std::getline`.

**EDIT** Actually, after reading `std::cin >> input[0] >> input[1]` the input buffer will still not be empty since it contains an `\n` character (after pressing ENTER). To empty input buffer try:

```
std::cin.clear(); // optional, use when input has gone bad; clears error flags
std::cin.sync(); // empty buffer
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is what is it that you want to read? If you want to read a line, you should use `getline`, if possible the one that takes a `std::string` as it will grow the string as needed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
   std::string line;
   std::getline( std::cin, line );
}
```

Comment: im makeing an encryption program just for fun.

Comment: it converts characters into numbers and how ever long the word is it adds that number to each number.

Comment: because typing a word or sentence is faster. plus that makes it harder does it not?

Comment: @Flyphe: The problem is that you are trying to use formatted input when you want to process unformatted data.

Comment: @Flyphe What the heck are you talking about? I said read, not write.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be my guess is that he thinks that if you read one char at the time, that you will also have to give it as input one char at the time (which is not true).